EIP712 vs EIP191(versionByte 0x00)
Help needed with little confusion I have.
EIP191 versionBytes 0x00 include the validator's address (verifying contract).
EIP712 has the domain separator including verifying contract.
If EIP712 is being followed with domain separator only including verifying contract, are they both acting same ? If so, version 0x01 (EIP712) is a successor to 0x00 ?

Please check this article; it might be helpful.
https://www.cyfrin.io/blog/understanding-ethereum-signature-standards-eip-191-eip-712

